# How to create multiple excel workbooks against the same application object?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I can create multiple workbooks against the same application object simply by using the ADD property twice in  row (see code below). But this is a tedious process if I want to create more number of workbooks. So I was wondering if there is a way to specify the number of workbooks that I want to create?

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Program
    'declaration statements
    Dim XL As Excel.Application
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
    
    Sub Main(args As String())
        XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        XL.Visible = True
        WB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
        WB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
        Console.ReadLine()
        oXL.Quit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: look for args received, use one of them as number of workbooks to create and iterate

Comment: @J.Salas which arguments are you talking about? Could you pls specify? If its the ADD method you are speaking of, then its argument does not accept any number which controls the number of workbooks to be created

Comment: Sub Main(args As String()) implies that your program is accepting args (this way Program.exe /numWorksheet = 10 /noVisible) you can read args Array and know what to do

Comment: `So I was wondering if there is a way to specify the number of workbooks` using the program's args is a way like @JoyG said. The question is how do you want to do it? Maybe just a `Dim numberOfWorkBooks = 5` in your method is enough if you the developer want to specify

Comment: @J.Salas thanks for the suggestion. However as a follow-up, wanted to ask if there is any direct command that can add multiple workbooks to the same application object. For example, when we create a workbook we can decide how many sheets it should have -- something similar to this?

Comment: @djv yes of course. That would definitely work. However requesting your attention to the above comment.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add?view=excel-pia

Comment: @J.Salas sorry to drag this. This is for Worksheets. But I was asking if something similar exists for workbooks?

Comment: Ups, sorry, no I belive that each WORKBOOK must be created and assigned to an object separately.

Comment: @J.Salas got it!!